# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I am new to Android development. I'm working on an project which involves using stubs for web services. When I try to use it, I get the following error:

[image]

I've been stuck here for a week, so some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'd post some code? It's absolutely impossible to understand what's wrong based on your question description.

Comment: Too little info for everyone to help. What is the THE you use? Give the whole stack trace. Some code will be of help too.

Comment: OP hasn't made the image visible. I've made an edit, image is at http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsdYk.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some packaging or deployment issues with the included libraries that you use in you project. This error is thrown when the `Java Virtual Machine` or a `ClassLoader` instace try to load the definition of the a class but cannot find it anywhere. In most cases, this occurs when something is messed up in your project configurations but i cannot tell what from the information provided. A solution would be to configure your project from the scratch since most of the times this is easier than finding what causes the problem. Also in case you had an older version of `ADT` (<17) the answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) might be usefull. Finally, if you are importing any javax libararies(or libraries that have javax components in them), this maybe the source of your problem since Adroid does not support the javax library.