# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime Android Widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

I have a problem during runtime of my Android widget with Android 2.3.3 and older.

When i install my widget on the screen, this error is printed :

```
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.myapp.StackWidgetService
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.app.myapp.StackWidgetProvider.onUpdate(StackWidgetProvider.java:229)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:61)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.app.mobideals.StackWidgetProvider.onReceive(StackWidgetProvider.java:216)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-03 10:26:31.127: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is due to the fact that the compilator don't arrive to perform the link to the StackWidgetService class at this line in onUpdate method of StackWidgetProvider class :

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // update each of the widgets with the remote adapter
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

            // Here we setup the intent which points to the StackViewService which will
            // provide the views for this collection.
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
```

The widget works well with other version of Android like 3.0, 4.0 etc...

Please help me :)

Comment: Have you declared the service in the Manifest?

Comment: Even i got the same issue. Did u solve this issue. please help me out in fixing this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have update your eclipse plugin to ADT 17 maybe your solution is here: [Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Take a look also here: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't seems to be this error. In fact, the problem is about the method :   `appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(i, R.id.stack_view);` This method is not available for min target sdk 10 as specified in my manifest :    `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="12" />` Because i would like to cover Android 2.3.3 (target 10) whereas before i was with min target = 11. How can i do in order to replace this method (notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged or introduce a condition to use this code only with target = 11 ?