# Android error - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have these log errors when launching my app:

```
> 05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tomsyweb.suna/com.tomsyweb.suna.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.tomsyweb.suna.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    ... 11 more
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    ... 21 more
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.<init>(StaggeredGridView.java:297)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.<init>(StaggeredGridView.java:304)
05-20 01:48:35.312: E/AndroidRuntime(23032):    ... 24 more
```

And the problem appeared just after installing Android SDK Tools Rev. 22, Android SDK Build-tools and updating Google Play Services.

Whereas in this error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat

and noting that for all "android.support.v4" import, the Javadoc isn't accessible

> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

the problem is probably due to the Android support library.

Hope all this information will help you find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Comment: most of the answers for eclipse. anyone give good solution for android studio

Comment: it happened for me in android studio, when my target sdk is 28, and running emulator api level 15, throws this error

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Right Click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export Tab.

Make sure that "Android Private Libraries" is checked for Export.

If you've added any libraries from the libs/ folder, remove them as they are automatically added in the "Android Private Libraries" section.

Comment: I have to do it for only my projects or also libraries?

Comment: If you have any Library projects, you'll need to do it for those too.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried numerous suggestions but this proved to be the solution.

Comment: i got the same issue and your answer is working for me as well..thanks a lot..:)

Comment: @VinaySShenoy plz help same problem i am facing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327657/class-not-found-exception-in-android/18327889?noredirect=1#18327889

Comment: @VinaySShenoy sir plz look at my problem also

Comment: And don't forget upgrade your Android build-tool! Old version make incorrect dex.

Answer (score 1):

I always get this and just restart eclipse to resolve it on MAC laptop.

Answer (score 1):

While your compile version is not the same with your Minimum Required SDK Version,android will create appcompat,the appcompat created may reference it's own `support-v4`,and the `support-v4` version may be different with the `support-v7` you have used,even you have an compatible `support-v4`.  I solved this problem just to have Minimum Required SDK version be same with compile version. Wish to help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the project - properties - java build path - Order and export - tick Android private libraries and all the libraries that u added

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

- List item
- Check Exports Order
- Enable Multi Dex
- Check api level of views in layout. I faced same problem with searchView. I have check api level while adding searchview but added implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener to class file.
- Check support Libraries v4,v7 etc

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check from official android documentation.

I've occurred this error below when running my apps to my minimum SDK (15):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.LongSparseArray.removeAt
```

After reading actual android documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LongSparseArray (sadly only added in API Level 16)

If you using 3rd-party libraries (in my case, I'm using **[Chuck](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck/issues/97)**), you might wanna ask them about supporting your minimum level SDK API. Otherwise, increase your minimum SDK to match the minimum API library had or do this (not recommended, will crash your apps)

```
// AndroidManifest
<manifest 
  <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.readystatesoftware.chuck, your.another.package.here" />

  <application>
  // ommited...
  </application>
</manifest
```