# Trying to store an AarryList of custom objects into shared preferences - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to stash my ArrayList of custom object into SharedPreference but I'm getting errors and at a total loss what to do.  Please can someone help me?

I've got my ArrayList of custom object which I then stash into another object so that I can create Json String object to store into sharedPreferences.Thus storing my ArrayList.

```
Here is the code that does this:
        ArrayList<SearchTerm> searchterms = new ArrayList<SearchTerm>();
        searchterms.add(new SearchTerm(query));
        Log.d(TAG, "object with attrb query added to ArrayList");
        //Placing ArrayList into another object to store in SharedPreferences
        searchterms_Wrapper = new ObjectForArrayList_searchTerms(searchterms);
        Log.d(TAG, "ArrayList added to another object ");
        // saving...
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String objectContainingSerchTerms = gson.toJson(searchterms_Wrapper);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
        .edit()
        .putString(SEARCH_TERM_ARRAY_LIST, objectContainingSerchTerms)
        .commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "searchTerm ArrayList saved...");
```

My classes:

```
public class SearchTerm implements Serializable {

private String searchTerm;

// Constructor
public SearchTerm(String searchTerm) {
    this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
```

...................

and:

```
public class ObjectForArrayList_searchTerms implements Serializable {
private ArrayList<SearchTerm> searchterms;

public ObjectForArrayList_searchTerms(ArrayList<SearchTerm> searchTerm) {
    this.searchterms = searchTerm;
}
```

StackTrace:

```
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689): Process: com.example.lifesci_pubmed, PID: 24689
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticleListFragment_develop.onOptionsItemSelected(ArticleListFragment_develop.java:428)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1612)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2018)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:379)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-13 22:31:49.971: E/AndroidRuntime(24689):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you added `GSON` library to your project ?

Comment: yes i have. the code does not give any red lines.

Comment: I have gson.2.3.jar present in my Referenced Libraries of my project

Comment: Try Checking the checkbox next to the lib (gson-2.3.jar) in: `Project Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Export` tab. Then do a clean/build.

Comment: ok. The box was not checked and so i checked it. upon re-launching the app I got the folloeing message: " could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method .....

Comment: okay. You relaunched the app after cleaning the project, right?

Comment: im sorry, how/what do you mean by "cleaning the project"

Comment: I mean before running the project, did you click on `Project` -> `Clean ..` ?

Comment: by the way, what does cleaning the project do exactly?

Comment: @user3274549 pretty much the same as any make file that has a clean option. It remove the objects that was compiled for runtime or any other runtime generated files etc. Usually you would do a clean and build, ie, clean your project and build.

Comment: +1 to what Janpan said.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse is a good read for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android error - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641739/android-error-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-ut) and only FSM knows how many others questions here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the checkbox next to the lib (gson-2.3.jar) in: `Project Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Export` tab. Then do a `clean` -> `build`.