# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, Android Studio 2.6.0, Inner class,

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

I got the following error at runtime: (All code is presented in the end.)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: se.domain.climbsweden.Area$MyFragmentPagerAdapter
```

at the following line:

```
this.mPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(f, fragments);
```

As I understand the error comes from when a class is unavailable at runtime but was available in compiling. Does it work in the same way in Android? I do find this strange because it is a inner class. I am using Android Studio 2.6.0 .

The goal for the code is to implement swiping in Android using a viewpager and the native activity. Thereof the use of v13 support package.

Could the error be related to a incorrect imported support-library?

Thanks in advance. These kind of error takes the motivation out of me!

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class Area extends Activity implements AreaFact.FactListener, AreaWall.WallListener {

    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_area);
        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the fragments to be paged
     */
    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AreaFact.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AreaWall.class.getName()));
        FragmentManager f = super.getFragmentManager();
        this.mPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(f, fragments);
        //
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.area_pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }

    private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy "android-support-v13.jar" from SDK_PATH\extras\android\support\v13; if it's not there, use the SDK manager to install or update "Extras/Android Support Library" into lib/ folder.

If it works then good.(worked for me)

If it gives error related to v4 classnotfound exception then -> 
Copy "android-support-v4.jar" from SDK_PATH\extras\android\support\v4; if it's not there, use the SDK manager to install or update "Extras/Android Support Library" into lib/ folder

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to eclipse android plugin, something similar on stackoverflow:
[Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)