# Fatel exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to send sms in android using `twilio`. but iam unable to send it is giving exception that

```
Fatel exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient
```

if iam trying to send sms in normal java program.it is working fine. if iam using same code in android it is giving above exception can i know How can i solve that exception.

and `MainActivity.java` is

```
  package com.example.smsthroughandroid;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.SmsFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Sms;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b1;
public static final String ACCOUNTSID = "AC126e8ddb3602a2ee77c1295c54b82fdc";
public static final String AUTHTOKEN = "04c75d5737fdd5cfb2d96f9678d1b4cd";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */

        try {
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);

        // Get the account and call factory class
        Account acct = client.getAccount();
        SmsFactory smsFactory = acct.getSmsFactory();
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("From","+13312096397");
        params.put("To", "+918095083152");
        params.put("Body", "Bad news " + "hai" + ", the server is down and it needs your help");

            // send an sms a call  
            // ( This makes a POST request to the SMS/Messages resource)
            Sms sms = smsFactory.create(params);
            System.out.println("Success sending SMS: " + sms.getSid());
        }
        catch (TwilioRestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "hai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

and my `activity_main.xml` is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

iam using following jars

```
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
gwt-twilio-1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.0.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.3.1.jar
twilio-java-sdk-3.3.14.jar
org.apache.commons.logging.jar

twilioclient-android-1.1.2-3635733.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use twilioclient-android's classes only, not twilio-java-sdk on your android app. Your imports must start with com.twilio.client.. See [this](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client)

Comment: I am using twilioclient-android-1.1.2-3635733.jar file

Comment: I don't see any references at your activity? As I see, you only added its jar to your app's buildpath. But you did not use it. Please remove twilio-java-sdk from your buildpath and use twilioclient-android's components.

Comment: Iam using all jars. in normal java progrm it is working fine but in android only problem

Comment: It is working fine on 'normal java' because twilio-java-sdk is for 'normal java'. For android you must build your client with   twilioclient-android api. You must use com.twilio.client.Device and com.twilio.client.Twilio classes at your activity.

Comment: iam using twilioclient-android-1.1.2-3635733.jar file

Comment: I don't see any references at your activity for twilioclient-android? Problem is you are triying to use standart java library (twilio-java-sdk) on android. You are not using twilioclient-android only adding its jar to buildpath and that does not mean that you are using it. Please see steps for using twilio on android. http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client

Comment: I have done it, but still sometimes i get error `BasicPhone.device.getState()` and sometimes in `device.connect(parameters,null)`. Do you also get??

Answer (score -2):

You must search on the web before asking any question. please refer to the link you find your answer.

[Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: i tested all jar files are includes

Comment: check them all. by clicking on the checkbox

Comment: i done but it is giving now FaTal Exception: java.lang.noSuchMethodError org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientManager

Comment: Android's internal copy of the Apache HTTP client classes is incomplete.  The library you are using may depend on one of the methods that has been removed to save space.  Unfortunately supplying your own is not an option because Android does not allow a user package to replace system-supplied ones.  You may have to recompile the library you are using to use a different package name, or you may need to find a version specifically built for Android.

Answer (score -2):

Try this- 1)  project-> config build path-> order and export-> move dependent project on top    else

2) Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.