# NoClassDefFoundError for Jersey 2.4.1 client in Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, jersey-client

I have an Android project targeting API 17 which needs to consume a Jersey 2.4.1 REST service. However, at runtime I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError for `org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig$1`. This class is in the Jersey JAR files I need for the client code.

I have followed instructions from other posts about the libs Android dependency fix e.g. [Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) but I still get the issue. The JAR is in the libs dir and I have checked the export option in the build path. What's weird is I have other jersey jars in this lib which are working, it just doesn't seem to find this one.

I have tried cleaning the project, refreshing it, removing and re-adding the JAR but I just can't seem to get it working. The class it complains about is in the jersey-common-2.4.1.jar which I can see in the Eclipse workspace so the right JAR is there, just seems it's not being exported with the APK.

**UPDATE**

I tried configuring ProGuard to see what gets produced but it was a never ending rabbit hole of warnings about classes and methods. In the end I just put `-ignorewarnings` in to get something output.

**UPDATE2**

I looked at the error message a little closer and it's actually missing `org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig$1` (note the $1). This is a static inner class which makes me almost certain that it's a ProGuard config issue. I tried adding:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class org.glassfish.jersey.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class javax.ws.rs.**
```

to my proguard-project.txt file but I still get the NoClassDefFoundError. How can I tell Eclipse/ProGuard to leave my library jars alone completely for both kinds of build options (right click deploy and export)?

**ANSWER/RESOLUTION**

See my comment in response to @pjco.

Comment: Have you taken a peek inside your apk to see which classes are included? Is Progard enabled, and if so, configured correctly?

Comment: I am getting this using the standard debug deployment from Eclipse i.e. RightClick > Run As... > Android Application. I tried using Export to APK and turned on ProGuard but now I am getting a heap load of Warnings. I think its going to take quite a while to figure out all this ProGuard stuff, surely I don't need this to do a simple deployment to the device (non release build)?

Comment: No you don't need proguard -- I asked because if you had it enabled, you could have easily seen the sort of thing you're seeing. So, look inside your APK to see what's missing.

Comment: Sorry @323go, I'm not really sure what I should be looking for (or not in this case). If I unpack the APK it looks like its packaged like a JAR. Following the directory structure I do see that there is no path for org/glassfish/jersey/model/internal. Other package paths exist for JARs in the Android Dependencies lib and they have a localization.properies and sometimes a build.properties in the directory. I guess this is the problem but how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Proguard isn't run by default.  The `$1` methods are generated by the compiler when an inner class tries to access something in the outer instance.  Methods with a dollar sign and number are not Proguard related. Proguard names methods with letters (a,b,c, etc).

The `libs` folder should be exported by default.  You should not need to configure the build path on recent versions of ADT (23).

Be sure to update ADT / build tools.  Try starting a new project with the wizard in eclipse and place the jar in your libs folder. Then call some function in your jar from your `MainActivity`.

Do **NOT** change anything on the `Java build path` or any other similar settings

Comment: I updated my all my Android tools and SDK and tried again but no luck. In the end I decided to add all jars I could find in another java client project I have which uses it successfully, and now it finds the class. The problem is dependencies, Jersey 2.4.1 requires not only a whole bunch of other jars but it also relies on classes from the JRE rt.jar e.g. (javax.xml.stream.*). I read somewhere that it's not good to use dependencies from there, so for this reason I think **I will scrap using Jersey as a client in Android**. Annoyed at all the wasted effort, now looking RESTDroid or Robospice

Comment: @rossco, which one did you end up using RESTDroid or Robospice?

Comment: Eventually implemented Robospice with the Retrofit library built in. It's pretty awesome, definitely recommend it if you are looking at consuming REST from Android.