# Suppressing/avoiding the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for classes created in the higher version of Android SDK

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I execute a code referencing the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback on Android phones running Android P and lower I get the following message in the logs:

*Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager$CellInfoCallback;*

I do not want this message to be spammed and visible to a customer. I've tried annotating the class using

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
class RadioCallback : TelephonyManager.CellInfoCallback() {
    override fun onCellInfo(p0: MutableList<CellInfo>) {
    }
}
```

and calls to this class are only made on Android Q:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val radioCallback = RadioCallback()
        telephonyManager.requestCellInfoUpdate(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, radioCallback)
    }
```

P.S. solutions from this thread [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on older Android SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790594/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-older-android-sdk-versions) are not helpful