# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager"

Tags: java, android

What is the reason for "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager"?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager
at com.campus.ReadingBeaconService.onStart(ReadingBeaconService.java:50)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2702)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check have you missed any library or dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Add your activity in your Manifest as

```
   <activity
      android:name=".YourActivity"/>
```

If you have added your activity in the manifest. Check whether the class name is right!!!

Comment: i have verified all are okay,Thanks

Comment: Not Resolving the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror    Check this link first.

Comment: beaconManger=new BeaconManager(ReadingBeaconService.this);
  
  beaconManger.connect(new ServiceReadyCallback() {
   
   @Override
   public void onServiceReady() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
     beaconManger.startRanging(new Region("r1", null, null, null));
    
     
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   }
  });